# $(a^2 + b^2) \bmod 4 \equiv 3 \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb Z $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove $(a^2 + b^2) \bmod 4 \equiv 3 \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb Z $

Comment: The squares $1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,\cdots$ are all either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$. Can we write $3$ mod $4$ as the sum of two numbers each either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$?

Answer (score 6):

- $0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4 $
- $1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $
- $2^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4 $
- $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $

Therefore $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0,1 \text{ or } 2 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $4$ divides $a^2+b^2-3$ so consider some cases for $a$ and $b$:

- if $a=2k,~~b=2k', k,k'\in \mathbb Z$ then $4\mid a^2+b^2-3$ lead us to $4\mid 3$ which is wrong.
- if $a=2k+1,~~b=2k', k,k'\in \mathbb Z$ then $4\mid a^2+b^2-3$ lead us to $4\mid 2$ which is wrong.
- if $a=2k+1,~~b=2k'+1, k,k'\in \mathbb Z$ then $4\mid a^2+b^2-3$ lead us to $4\mid 1$ which is wrong.

Comment: Nice $+1\quad$ :^D

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $a\equiv 0\pmod 4$, then $a^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$. If $a\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then $a^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$. If $a\equiv 2\pmod 4$, then $a^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$. If $a\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $a^2\equiv 9\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Consider the possible cases for $a$ and $b$.